# Python: Android App Automation : Unable to select from Number picker

Tags: android, python, automation, appium, numberpicker

I am doing Android App Automation using Appium and Python,
I am stuck at place where i have to select value from Numberpicker.
I tried send_keys, Click, swipe but no luck

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KncRv.png)
[image]

Comment: First Select xpath of number wheel & give the index as here 2 wheels are displayed so for selecting first wheel I have used index=0.e.g driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='0']")).sendKeys("0 years");

Comment: @SnehaShinde Hi sneha thanks for the help. but its not working.as it has same index value for month and year.can you help me with how to find xpath in this?

Comment: But I can see the index is 0 for year & 1 is for month

Comment: @SnehaShinde No index is same for both..you are asking for Numberpicker or what? Also as i asked my devloper he is saying that edit text will not work here as this is not editatble

Comment: List<WebElement> date = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));           

date.get(1).sendKeys("1 years");

Comment: Have you tried above code?is it working?

Comment: yes tried. its not working :(..it is not showing error also.

Comment: can you share screenshot when Pointer is on (0)NumberPicker[200,372][328,732]

Comment: @SnehaShinde hi

Comment: Hi@ tanvi joshi

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer. Recently work need it so I collect info from web and made this solution.

Just

1. select element
2. click element for made it select
3. put delete key times
4. set value

```
month="Sep"
month_ui = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[1]//android.widget.EditText")   # get month
month_ui.click()                                        # select origin month txt
month_ori=str(month_ui.get_attribute("text"))           # get origin month txt
for i in range(len(month_ori)):                         # delete-key click times
    driver.press_keycode(67)
driver.set_value(month_ui, month)                       # set value
```

[image]